# Unable to parse boolean value into postgresql DB

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to insert data from spreadhseet.csv to my database, but unable to parse the boolean value. It always takes boolean value as false for all the columns.

In my spreadhseet, I have both true and false, but when I upload into DB, it keeps all coumns as false.

I am trying to parse in_service attribute which has boolean values as TRUE or FALSE

I need both the values ( true and false)

Hope I am doing it right?

```
try {
            // read line
            String[] fileData;
            String line = dis.readLine().replaceAll("\"", "");
            fileData = line.split(",");
            int tripID = Integer.parseInt(fileData[0]);
            int driver_id = Integer.parseInt(fileData[1]);
            String timestamp = fileData[2];
            boolean in_service = Boolean.parseBoolean(fileData[3]);
            int trips_pos = Integer.parseInt(fileData[4]);
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(fileData[5]);
            double lon = Double.parseDouble(fileData[6]);
            int parish_id = Integer.parseInt(fileData[7]);
            double distance = Double.parseDouble(fileData[8]);
            int duration = Integer.parseInt(fileData[9]);
            int trip_id = Integer.parseInt(fileData[10]);
            double taxi_fare = Double.parseDouble(fileData[11]);



            String query = " INSERT INTO aid_atidivyakumarpatra "
                    + "(id, driver_id, date, in_service, trips_pos, lat, lon, point, parish_id, distance, duration, trip_id, taxi_fare)"
                    + "VALUES ("+tripID+","+driver_id+",'"+timestamp+"',"+in_service+","+trips_pos+","
                    + lat+","+lon+",ST_GeomFromText('POINT("+lon+" "+lat+")', 4326) , "+parish_id+","+distance+","+duration+", "
                    + trip_id +","+taxi_fare +")";
```

Comment: SQL Injection alert!

Comment: The error is with the java code not with the SQL query

Comment: If you read the Javadoc on parseBoolean (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean(java.lang.String)), it says that the only way it returns true is if the String it parses is equal to case insensitive value of "true".

Comment: If you have a value with single quote, you break your SQL statement.

Comment: 1. Why don't you use PreparedStatement? 2. Have you tried to print out generated query and call it directly on db for *true* value?

Comment: @Orin2005 *TRUE* fulfills this condition.

Comment: @agad he didn't mention that at the time of my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my answer but the real question is Why you are not handling database with JPA (Java Persistence API)?
(entity managers,Query,etc...)

With that kind of insert statements (concatenation), is very high the possible SQL Injection Attack (I agree with Reimeus)